# Почему массив не отображается в пикере?

Tags: swift, swift4, uikit

Почему мой массив не отображается в пикере?

```
    // Array of values in picker
let numeralSystems = ["16 NS","10 NS", "8 NS", "2 NS" ]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numeralSystems[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numeralSystems.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    fromLabel.text = numeralSystems[row]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите делегат для протокола `UIPickerViewDataSource`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.delegate = self
}
```

Добавьте протокол для контроллера:

```
class TheNameOfYourController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource {}
```

Comment: А куда его нужно вставить?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеев где вы пикер создаете? Программно или сториборд?

Comment: Виталий,я его создаю в сториборде

Comment: @МаксимАлексеев посмотрите обновление